# Django - 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to serve images from the database with django, but when I add

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to my urlpatterns i get this error: TypeError at /: module object is not callable

this is the traceback:

```
File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.         resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)

File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in resolve
  494.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:

File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  36.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in url_patterns
  536.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  36.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  529.             return import_module(self.urlconf_name)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _gcd_import
  994. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _find_and_load
  971. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _find_and_load_unlocked
  955. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _load_unlocked
  665. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>" in exec_module
  678. <source code not available>

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>" in _call_with_frames_removed
  219. <source code not available>

File "/home/watch/Documents/projects/herokuapp/mysite/mysite/urls.py" in <module>
  27. ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried using it in both the main urls.py and the app urls.py, but it didn't work.

my media_root and media_urls are the following:

```
abspath = lambda *p: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*p))

PROJECT_ROOT = abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

i tried reimporting everything with

```
from django.conf.urls import *
```

but it didn't work either.

edit, these are my imports:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import static
from django.conf import settings
```

I'm using the last version of django and deploying in heroku (locally with heroku local)

Comment: You need to show the imports you are using in that file. How *exactly* are you importing `static`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change

```
from django.conf.urls import static
```

to

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

write this line, Instead of

```
from django.conf.urls import static
```

Comment: Hi there, you can use code block to format your code to be more readable using backticks like so:
```python
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```